# Sanitizing URL strings

Tags: ruby

Say we have a string

```
url = "http://example.com/foo/baz/../../."
```

Obviously, we know from the Unix shell that `../../.` essentially means to go up two directories. Hence, this URL is really going to `http://example.com/`. My question is, given these `../` characters in a string, how can we sanitize the URL string to point at the actual resource?

For example:

```
url = "http://example.com/foo/baz/../../hello.html"
url = process(url)
url = "http://example.com/hello.html"
```

Another:

```
url = "http://example.com/foo/baz/../."
url = process(url)
url = "http://example.com/foo/"
```

Keep in mind, the function still as to be able to take in normal URLs (ie. `http://example.com`) and return them as is if there is nothing to sanitize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [addressable](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable) gem can do this.

```
require 'addressable'
Addressable::URI.parse("http://example.com/foo/baz/../../hello.html").normalize.to_s
#=> "http://example.com/hello.html"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# ======
## defs:

def process(url)
  url_components = url.split('/')
  url_components2 = url_components.dup

  current_index = 0

  url_components.each do |component|

    if component == '..'
      url_components2.delete_at(current_index)
      url_components2.delete_at(current_index-1)
      current_index -= 1
    elsif
      component == '.'
      url_components2.delete_at(current_index)
    else
      current_index += 1
    end

  end

  url_resolved = url_components2.join('/')
  return url_resolved
end


# =======
## tests:

urls = [
  "http://example.com/foo/baz/../../.",
  "http://example.com/foo/baz/../../hello.html",
  "http://example.com/foo/baz/../."
]

urls.each do |url|
  print url, ' => '
  puts process(url)
end
```